# Fallback for R32F alpha blending

Tags: shaders, alpha-blending, floating-point, hardware-acceleration

I'm rendering an aggregation of value into an R32F format texture, using alpha blending to accomplish the sum operation.

R32F alpha blending is not supported on all hardware. What kind of fallback options do I have for accomplishing the addition in when the hardware doesn't support blending?

Comment: Just don't support that hardware?  IIRC all DX10+ class hardware should support R32F blending, so it wouldn't be unreasonable.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou I would like to support DX9+ cards if possible.